# my webkit scrollbar is working when the screen is smaller, but in fullscreen, it goes back to the standard scrollbar

Tags: html, webkit, scrollbar

i have my custom scrollbar working whenever my screen is smaller, and i tried a bunch of different codes in order to fix the customization from disappearing, but nothing has worked.

heres what my code looks like.

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width:15px;
  overflow:auto;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #c81be4
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e569f6; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #c81be4
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #a33cc3; 
  
}
```